# how to make values on table ascend or descend

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I currently have a table on my site but I need there to be a icon or something next to the text on the categories in the table to make the values ascend alphabetically, I have no idea how to do this and I have looked.

[image]

Here is my code- (Yes I know its insecure w/ mysql_connect)

```
<?php       
    $username="dfgdfg";
    $password="dfgdfg";
    $database="dfg";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    if (isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $columbname = $_POST['selectitem'];
        $searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
        $query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
        $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient'";
        $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    mysql_close();
?>

<table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr valign="bottom" bgcolor="#000000">
        <td width="24"><span class="style1b"><strong>No.</strong></span></td>
        <td width="105"><span class="style1b"><strong>Date</strong></span></td>
        <!--<td width="57"><span class="style1b"><strong>Agent/client</strong></span></td>-->
        <td width="120"><span class="style1b"><strong>Property/Description</strong></span></td>
        <td width="199"><span class="style1b"><strong>Transaction type </strong></span></td>
        <td width="235"><span class="style1b"><strong>Applicable document </strong></span></td>
        <td width="58"><span class="style1b"><strong>Received</strong></span></td>
        <td width="58"><span class="style1b"><strong>Paid</strong></span></td>
    </tr>

<?php

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {

    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    //$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"agentclientt");
    $f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"propertydescription");
    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"transactiontype");
    $f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"applicabledocument"); 
    $f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"received");
    $f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"paid");

?>
    <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td><?php echo $f1; ?></td> <!--id-->
        <td><?php echo $f2; ?></td> <!--date-->
        <!-- <td><?php //echo $f3; ?></td> --><!--agent/client-->
        <td><?php echo $f4; ?></td> <!--desc-->
        <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td> <!--type-->
        <td><a href="/manage/clientdoc/<?php echo $f6; ?>"><?php echo $f6; ?></a></td> <!--document-->
        <td><?php echo $f7; ?></td> <!--recived-->
        <td><?php echo $f8; ?></td> <!--paid-->
    </tr>    

<?php
    $i++;
    }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: If the table display all the data, you can sort it on client side using javascript.

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/ - a jQuery plugin - will make your life easy if you "have no idea how to do this"

Comment: Is there currently _any_ JavaScript?

Comment: You can try http://www.datatables.net/ , it's well documented and easy to setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an icon add the link to parametr when you will be checking what field and what type of sorting he chose and use in query

`ORDER BY ASC` or `ORDER BY DESC`

for example

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' ORDER BY ASC
```

In way you presented it it's submited via POST so it'd be good to add select box with fields and radio/select box with type of sorting

```
 <select name="sortby">
    <option value="agentClient">Client agent</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
 </select>
 <select name="orderby">
    <option value="desc" selected>Descending</option>
    <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
 </select>
```

then in post add to query

```
$sorted_fields_avaiable = array('agentClient', 'name');
$sorting = "";
if(in_array($_POST['sortby'], $sorted_fields_avaiable)
{
   $sorting .= "ORDER BY ".$_POST['sortby'];
   if($_POST['orderby'] == 'asc') $sorting .= " ASC";
   else $sorting .= ' DESC';
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' $sorting";
```

Remember also that is is only to show you idea, you should consider using **mysqli** or **pdo** with binding params and prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

If your table has huge amount of rows, dont use javascript sorting.Use server side sorting.
Ref link for server side sorting - http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/276091-help-with-search-sorting-and-pagination/

Answer (score 1):

Change your your as... You can sort data according to field name..

order by fieldname ASC--- OR --- order by fieldname DESC
Note: default sort is accending

```
 "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname LIKE '%$searchterm%' ORDER BY agentclient  ASC";

    $query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' ORDER BY agentclient ASC ";
```